# How to add multiple headers and footers in pdf using itext

Tags: java, itext

In my pdf I need to have more than one header and footer.In header I want title heading on left and some text on the center.

Likewise in footer I need to print my company name on the left side,page number on center and some info regarding the contents in my table on the right side.

I have seen so many posts but I didn't get the correct idea for creating this.Somebody please help me with some example code snippets.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Headers and footers should be added using 'page events'. If you need some examples, just look for the keyword [header](https://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/header) / [footer](https://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/footer) on the official web site.

Just create a class that extends `PdfPageEventHelper` and implement the `onEndPage()` method. People who read the documentation do not make the common mistake to use the `onStartPage()` method, but maybe you overlooked this, so I'm adding this as an extra caveat.

Add an instance of your class to the PdfWriter object with the `setPageEvent()` method.

I don't know if I understand what you mean by "multiple" headers. If you have more than one page event implementation, you can add them all using the `setPageEvent()` method and they will all be executed. If you want to switch from one page event implementation to another, you need to use `setPageEvent(null)` first.

Maybe you want the header to be different for different pages, just use a member-variable in your page event implementation and change it along the way. In one of the book examples named [MovieHistory2](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-5#228-moviehistory2.java), the text for the header is stored in a `String` array named `header`.

The position of the header depends on the page number:

```
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        Rectangle rect = writer.getBoxSize("art");
        switch(writer.getPageNumber() % 2) {
        case 0:
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
                    Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, header[0],
                    rect.getRight(), rect.getTop(), 0);
            break;
        case 1:
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
                    Element.ALIGN_LEFT, header[1],
                    rect.getLeft(), rect.getTop(), 0);
            break;
        }
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
                Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(String.format("page %d", pagenumber)),
                (rect.getLeft() + rect.getRight()) / 2, rect.getBottom() - 18, 0);
    }
```

For even page numbers, the header is added to the right; for odd page numbers to the left. The footer is centered as you can see.

You also mention a header table. If you want to use a table, please take a look at the [MovieCountries1](https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-5#225-moviecountries1.java) example.

You say: "I have seen so many posts but I didn't get the correct idea for creating this." You will get the correct idea by reading the documentation, more specifically chapter 5 of the book "iText in Action — Second Edition" from which the code snippets I'm referring to are taken.