# ItextPdf Width Does Not Expand for Landscape Page

Tags: java, itext, width, landscape

I am trying to put a table on a PDF page that has been rotated for landscape in my 'PdfPageEventHelper':

```
public void onStartPage(PdfWriter writer_,Document document_) {
        writer_.addPageDictEntry(PdfName.ROTATE,PdfPage.LANDSCAPE);
    }
```

That part seems to be working but when I create my table with 10 columns, setting the width does not seem to work:

```
float sizeY=page.getWidth();
PdfPTable table=new PdfPTable(10);
table.setTotalWidth(sizeY);
float[] widths=new float[] {1.f,1.5f,4.f,1.f,1.f,1.f,1.f,1.f,1.f,1.f};
table.setWidths(widths);
```

The table width always seems to be the default (80% of the portrait page width). How do I get the table to use the landscape page width? TIA.

Comment: Your page event code is good for situations in which you want to fill a page in the normal document orientation and then rotate the so filled page (to finally have a landscape page with non-upright text). If you want to use a landscape format with upright text, simply set the document size to a landscape format before the page in question is created (for the first page even before `open`ing the `Document` instance.)

Comment: Thanks. I did that originally but still got the same result. The table will not expand beyond the smallest dimension. In any case doing it that way left the orientation in portrait. I had to rotate it with the PDF viewer rather than it displaying in landscape to start. This way displays in landscape without rotating it with the viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the old iText 5. There are plenty of quirks in iText 5 that are solved in iText 7.

In iText 7, we have the concept of the `UnitValue` which helps iText determine whether something is an absolute value (in user units / points) or a relative value (a percentage).

In iText 5, this concept is unknown. The `PdfPTable` class has two parameters for the width of a table:

- The width as a percentage: 80% by default,
- The absolute width

By default, the width as a percentage is used. If you want to use the absolute width, you need to "pull the switch" with the `setLockedWidth()` method:

```
table.setTotalWidth(sizeY);
table.setLockedWidth(true);
```

I know this is odd, but then again, you are using the *old* iText version. If you want a more consistent API, please use iText 7. That upgrade is really significant. We've spent an awful amount of time and money on improving iText, so it's kind of frustrating to see that new iText developers choose to work with iText 5 rather than with iText 7.

Comment: Bingo. That was it. Thanks. I now need to figure out why Eclipse is not updating to iText 7 but that is my problem now.

Comment: iText 7 is a complete rewrite of iText 5. If you would just upgrade, you would break existing code.

Comment: Hmm, since I am just starting this code it might behoove me to do it now. I am guessing I need to import a different Maven dependency.

Comment: It's all here: https://developers.itextpdf.com/itext7/download-and-install-information/Java